# Parboiled2 Parser Example

Tags: scala, parsing, parboiled2

I'm trying to try out this example from [parboiled2](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2):

```
scala> class MyParser(val input: org.parboiled2.ParserInput) 
            extends org.parboiled2.Parser { 
                def f = rule { capture("foo" ~ push(42)) 
                } 
        }
defined class MyParser
```

Then, I create a new `MyParser` with input of `"foo"`.

```
scala> new MyParser("foo").f
res11: org.parboiled2.Rule[shapeless.HNil,shapeless.::
            [Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] = null
```

Yet the return value is `null`.

How can I run this simple `f` *Rule* from the REPL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parboiled 2's `rule` is a macro, and methods that are defined using `rule` aren't intended to be referred to outside of the context of other rules or a call to `run()`. So if you have the following:

```
import org.parboiled2._

class MyParser(val input: ParserInput) extends Parser {
  def f = rule { capture("foo" ~ push(42)) } 
}
```

You can use it like this (with the type cleaned up for clarity):

```
scala>  new MyParser("foo").f.run()
res0: scala.util.Try[Int :: String :: HNil] = Success(42 :: foo :: HNil)
```

If you don't want a `Try` you can use one of the other [delivery schemes](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#alternative-deliveryschemes).